# Runtime control of parametric function parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, types

I have the following parametric function in Scala:

```
implicit class X(str: String) {
  def toPositiveNumeric[T >: Int with Long with Float with Double <: AnyVal]
  (implicit ev: T => Ordered[T], ctag: ClassTag[T]): T = ???
}
```

And I want to call in a unit test, where I will have various types and values:

```
Array(Array(Int.getClass, "123"), Array(Double.getClass, "123"))
  .foreach { case Array(tpe, str) => 
     assert(str.toPositiveNumeric[tpe] == 123.asInstanceOf[tpe])
```

This does **not** work as is, because `tpe` won't work in those places. Is there any way to make this work, or is this mixing runtime and compile time in an intractable way?

Comment: Sounds like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: the type in ```[]``` is something that should be resolved in compile time and in runtime there is no information about type at all